# Sending mail in Paypal IPN listener page does not work

Tags: asp.net, email, paypal, paypal-ipn, sendgrid

I'm working on windows Azure ASP.NET integrating Paypal in it.
I succeeded creating the listener page in my website. After  "VERIFIED" was received the page updates the database as I requested, but I cant send a mail - I don't get an error message, but the mail isn't in the inbox (I'm using sendGrid).
I can send a mail in other pages of my website.
What is the best way to send a mail from the listener page in asp.net?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the script is running but your email isn't getting sent then there must be some sort of an error happening, or may be a simple logic flaw in your code.

I wrote this article a while back on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  I'd recommend taking a look at it and following the steps.  It will help you track down the problem and get it resolved.

Comment: I'm thinking a problem could be with Azure, (They use somewhat _dedicated_ firewalls, and Paypal IPN may not be able to listen to it due those protections) and seeing as Paypal IPN only works with "public pages" Microsoft Azure may _not_ be the best choice for a site that uses Paypal IPN. (Or, anything Paypal, I guess.)